# How to define constraint for consecutive elements?

Tags: definition, constraints

I have a sequence denoted by $\vec{x}=(x_1,\dots,x_M), x_i\in\{1,\dots,N\} $. The sequence $\vec{x}$ can later be encoded into another sequence $\vec{c}=(f(x_1),\dots,f(x_M)), f: \{1,\dots,N\} \mapsto \{1,\dots,L\}$.
How to define a constraint so that the sequence $\vec{x}$ is valid only if after the encoding, $\vec{c}$ can have the same numbers if they are consecutive?

For example,

$M=N=5, L=3$

$\vec{c^1}=(3,3,1,2,2)$ is allowed, but

$\vec{c^2}=(3,1,3,2,2)$ is not allowed because the first and the third element is the same but not consecutive,

$\vec{c^3}=(3,3,2,2,2)$ is also allowed.

Thank You.

Edit:
I was unclear on which variable to put the constraint on. I was meant to define the constraint on the sequence $\vec{x}$.

Comment: How about $|c_{i+1}-c_i| \le1$?  You should think about whether this applies at the wraparound.

Comment: Hi @RossMillikan, I just edited the answer, sorry for being unclear before. I meant to put the constraint on the sequence $\vec{x}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x_{i}$ is valid if $\nexists j < i$, for which $f(x_{j}) \neq f(x_{i})$, when $\exists k < j$, for which $f(x_{k}) = f(x_{i})$.

Comment: Hi thanks, but I just edited the answer. Sorry for being unclear, I meant to put the constraint on $\vec{x}$ instead of the function $f(x)$.

Comment: Updated for $x_{i}$ instead of $f(x_{i})$.

Comment: I see, we can constraint its element. Thank you so much. Just one more question, how to define this constraint in an "equation" ? I mean after the sentence "Subject to:" in a problem definition, or is this an acceptable form of constraint in such problem definition. This is actually my original doubt.

Comment: Honestly speaking, I tried to write it up with only math symbols, but I couldn't get the whole thing right.

Comment: I see, then maybe I should just rephrase your answer in the problem explanation instead of making it a constraint in the problem definition. Thank you so much.

Comment: As a constraint, I would put $x_{i} \in X$, and define $X$ before/after.